# How to export a dotted function, such as fs.readdir(__dirname, callback() {})?

Tags: node.js, export

I'm unsure of the proper way to export a "module.method" - fs.readdir()?

**file-explorer.js**

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , stdin = process.stdin
  , stdout = process.stdout


fs.readdir(__dirname, function (err, files) {
    // file handlers here
});
```

Do I need to wrap it in a function like below is there a better way?

```
var see_files = function() {
   fs.readdir(__dirname, function (err, files) {
        // file handlers here
    });
};

exports.see_files       = see_files;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
exports.see_files = function() {
   fs.readdir(__dirname, function (err, files) {
        // file handlers here
    });
};
```

Comment: So, is wrapping is the best way to do this? That's simpler although it's nice to keep all exports in one place so you can see what's available in the module in a glance.

Comment: Usually you have a lot of functions in a file and you only want a few of them to be exposed to the outside to keep the api clean, so there is no way arround the "wrapping" is the only way.